# How to check for collision on canvas for objects created from the same class?

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, collision-detection

I am building a ball physics simulator in Javascript. I understand how to detect collisions for individually created objects, but struggle when the objects are constructed using ES6 classes. Here is the code I have so far.

Ball Constructor

```
const Ball = class {
  constructor(x, y, dx, dy) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.dx = dx;
    this.dy = dy;
  }

  checkForWall() {
    if (this.x + ballRadius < ballRadius) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
    }
    if (this.y + ballRadius < ballRadius) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
    }
    if (this.x + ballRadius > canvas.width) {
      this.dx = -this.dx;
    }
    if (this.y + ballRadius > canvas.height) {
      this.dy = -this.dy;
    }
  }

  moveBall() {
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;
  }
};
```

Ball Drawing Function on Canvas

```
const drawBalls = function (x, y) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.fillStyle = `green`;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
};
```

Drawing Function on canvas with interval timer

```
const draw = function () {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.clientHeight);
  drawBalls(ballOne.x, ballOne.y);
  drawBalls(ballTwo.x, ballTwo.y);
  ballTwo.moveBall();
  ballTwo.checkForWall();
  ballOne.moveBall();
  ballOne.checkForWall();
}

let interval = setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Is there a way to implement code in the above class to check whether or not balls constructed from this class have collided with other balls constructed from the same class in the same way that I am able to check for collision with the canvas walls? Do I need to create a parent class and a child class?

Comment: I'm not sure you know what a class is. It sounds like you need multiple implementations of a class. A class itself does nothing until you instanciate it. In terms of collisions. If you've already written this logic once, introducing a class should essentially be the same thing. All in all this question is not clear at all.

Comment: I am using canvas. I recognize that the class will not do anything until I instantiate it, and that's my fault for not making the question clearer. I have edited the question for clarity.